# Comprehensive list - Running code in batch file vs. entering code directly into console

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a comprehensive list of differences between running the exact same code in the windows cmd windows (entering it manually, line by line) vs. writing a batch file and running that.

I cannot possibly be the fist person to ask this, but neither Google nor multiple stack overflow searches returned what I wanted. I mostly get comparison between [.bat & .cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd?rq=1) like this one, or [specific questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095708/batch-script-vs-command-line) about [a single issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383667/running-command-line-in-batch-file). I know there are other differences, for example i just found out that

```
set "filename=foo"
set "optional_postfix="
set "filetype=.cpp"

set completename=%filename%%optional_postfix%%filetype%
echo %completename%
PAUSE
```

behave differently.

I would like to read up on all of the differences since finding out about them after trying something for half an hour that *should* work and finding out about the difference afterwards is pretty annoying.

If such a list already exists here, please do not downvote me, I actually spent time looking for it and - at least for me - it was not obvious how to find it. Others might have the same issue, so please just mark it as duplicate.

Comment: At first, reference this thread: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133)

Comment: Quick reply out of my head: some commands do not work in `cmd`: `goto`, `shift`, `setlocal`, `endlocal`, and `call :Label`; ; `set /A` writes the (last) result to console in `cmd` but not in batch files; there is no [argument expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html); undefined environment variables expand to empty strings in batch files but are maintained literally in `cmd`; `%%` become a literal `%` in batch files but not in `cmd`; that is why you have to state `for %%I in ...` in batch files, but `for %I in ...` in `cmd`; and a few commands may or may not reset `ErrorLevel`...

Comment: @aschipfl: Thanks for the link, this seems to be a good start. No wonder I didn't find it by searching, I would never have guessed it contains what I am looking for just by reading the title.

Comment: Although the topic is different, you may review a list of these differences and whole examples of how to use such command-line commands _not_ in a Batch file at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extension/13337597#13337597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous differences whether commands are executed in `cmd` or in batch file context, all of which refer to `cmd`-internal commands or features though.

The following commands that do nothing when executed in `cmd` context (they do not produce any output and do not affect [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)):

- `goto`
- `shift`
- `setlocal` (to en-/disable command extensions or delayed expansion in `cmd`, invoke the instance using `cmd /E:{ON|OFF} /V:{ON|OFF}` instead)
- `endlocal`

Labels (like `:Label`) cannot be used in `cmd`, they are simply ignored. Therefore `call :Label` cannot be used too (if you do, an error message appears and `ErrorLevel` becomes set to `1`).

There is of course no [argument expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in `cmd` since there is no possibility to provide arguments. Hence a string like `%1` is just returned as is ( try with `echo %1`). This allows to define variable names in `cmd` that begin with a numerical digit, which is not possible in batch files (actually you can define them, but you cannot `%`-expand them; try this in a batch file: `set "123=abc"`, then `set 1`; you will get the output `123=abc`; but trying to do `echo %123%` will result in the output `23`, because `%1` is recognised as argument reference (given that no argument is supplied)).

Undefined environment variables are not expanded (replaced) in `cmd` but they are maintained literally (do `set "VAR="` and `echo %VAR%`, so you get `%VAR%`). In batch files however, they are expanded to empty strings instead. Note that in batch files but not in `cmd`, two consecutive percent signs `%%` are replaced by a single one `%`. Also in batch files but not in `cmd`, a single `%` sign becomes removed.

More information about the percent expansion (both argument references and environment variables) can be found in this thread: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699)

The `set /A` command behaves differently: in `cmd` it returns the (last) result of an expression on the console (without trailing line-break), but in batch files it does not return anything.

The `for` command requires its loop variable references to be preceeded by two percent signs (like `for %%I in ...`) in batch files, but only a single one (like `for %I in ...`) in `cmd`. This is a consequence of the different percent expansion handling in batch files and in `cmd`.

Finally, some commands do not reset the `ErrorLevel` upon success, unless they are used within a batch file with `.cmd` extension. These are:

- `assoc`
- `dpath`
- `ftype`
- `path`
- `prompt`
- `set`

More information about resetting the `ErrorLevel` can be found in this post: [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968021)